# Convert integer to hexadecimal

Tags: objective-c, c

I just need to convert integer to hexadecimal. Actually I have a char array in which I am storing hex values.

```
int var;
var=[self getValue];
char hexValues[5];
hexValues[0]= 0x02;
hexValues[1]= 0x04;
hexValues[2]= [self getHexFromInt:var];
```

Now what I think `getHexFromInt()` returns an `hex int` value equivalent to the passed decimal `"var"`. It will not contain `0x`.. format that's why I think char array will accept it as normal char. So please suggest me how can I return a char in `"0x`.." format from `getHexFromInt()`  method.

Comment: Decimal and hexadecimal are just representations for the same value.

Answer (score 3):

a hex value IS an integer value

hexadecimal is just a way of displaying an integer.

if you want to create a string that is the hexadecimal representation of an integer, you can go:

```
char hexStr[20];
sprintf(hexStr,"0x%x",var);
```

you can also pad the number with zeros if you want, by going %0(total number of digits desired)x

eg:

```
int var = 0x123;
sprintf(hexStr,"0x%08x",var);
```

will result in hexStr being filled with "0x00000123"