# C - how do I convert char(8-bit) to ascii format

Tags: c, char, hex, ascii

I wonder how to convert like a char: 1101_0110(D6) to two char(ascii format) 0100_0100(44) and 0011_0110(36).
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert integer to hexadecimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706846/convert-integer-to-hexadecimal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sample code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char x = '\xD6';
    char asc[3];
    sprintf(asc, "%02X", (unsigned char)x);
    printf("%s\n", asc);//D6
}
```